# Previewing content on site before going live

Tags: channel-entries, status

I'm currently looking for a neat way to preview content before it gets set live. The ideal setup would be to have a status "draft" that is shown on the frontend to super-admin and maybe other CMS user groups if setup.

I've played with the live look feature but I think it would be nicer to switch the status parameter in the tags depending on the user logged in group_id.

The problem I have come up against is the parsing order.

This post looks like its doing exactly what I want http://themetaq.com/articles/a-better-way-to-preview-entries-in-expressionengine but couldn't get this to work.

I want to keep this as out of the box as possible, rather than a using an add-on.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly couldn't you get to work from the article? There are three options listed there.

Comment: I got the varible coming out from stash fine but not when it was added into the entry tag. I added the parse="inward".

Comment: BTW, Stash (and Low Variables, imo) should be consider a part of the EE box now because of how it helps performance. Using defaults methods will usually require a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited]

If you are using Low Variables (or some other add-on) that allows global variables to be parsed early, you can do this...

--ORIGINAL POST--

The way to do this without an add-on is to use a snippet with simple conditionals.

Create a snippet `sn-statuses` with:

```
{if logged_in_member_id == "1"}Open|Draft{/if} 
{if logged_in_member_id != "1"}Open{/if}
```

Then, in your template, pull in the snippet:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" status="{sn-statuses}"}
```

Comment: I don't believe this works because `logged_in_member_id` are global variables. They are parsed after the `exp:channel:entries`.

Comment: Dangit. I have Low Variables installed. :)

Comment: Perfect. But rather than Low Variables, which looks cool but I  wanted to avoid the additional expense for each client site, I used the [link](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/global-member-vars) extension.

Comment: @StephenCallender, please, add a warning to your answer. If you to move the user related variables to be parsed early, you should never, ever, ever to enable the page template.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to always work without add-ons, if I can.

I use to create a snippet with this code and put it inside the `exp:channel:entries`:

```
{if status !="open" OR entry_date > current_time}
    {if author_id != logged_in_member_id AND logged_in_group_id != 1}
        {redirect="404"}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

If `open` isn't the only status the users can see, you can improve the code:

```
{if status != "open" && status != "featured" OR entry_date > current_time}
    {if author_id != logged_in_member_id AND logged_in_group_id != 1}
        {redirect="404"}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

I prefer to check for `status` that are different for the open ones because, sometimes, a new one can be created and maybe it shouldn't be viewed yet.

Comment: I like this method and think for an add-on-free option, this is best. Instead of redirecting, I'd probably just say, "This page is not available for viewing (yet). Check back later."

Comment: The live view links use `entry_ids` and usually the final URLs of an entry use `entry_title`. So, I believe it's better to not call the users to come back later.

Plus, you gonna need an `{if:else}` for this.

Answer (score 1):

**The Stash method.**

(I know you want an add-on-free version, but why? Stash is free, supported, and helps with performance.)

Toward the top of your template set the statuses based on the group_id of logged in member.

```
{exp:stash:set name="statuses"}{if group_id == "1" || group_id == "6"}open|draft{if:else}open{/if}{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then get that variable in your channel entries tag pair.

```
{exp:channel:entries status="{exp:stash:get name='statuses' parse_tags='yes' parse_conditionals='yes'}" channel="my_channel" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
  {exp:stash:set_list name="blog_listing" parse_tags="yes"}
   ....
```

Comment: By Add-on free i mean avoiding a feature full module type thing which is an extra thing that clients need to be told about. Actually stash or global_member_vars (mentioned above) are ideal. And your idea about creating the snippet which betters embedded into the entries tag is great- thanks!

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear. Whichever method you choose, please be sure mark it correct when the site allows you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a small add-on for this. It essentially creates/turns some user variables into early global config vars

> This extension adds logged_in_member_id and logged_in_group_id to the
>   global variables array so they are parsed early and can be used in
>   simple conditionals.

```
  {if logged_in_member_id != "0"}
    {exp:channel:entries status="open|members_only"}
    ...
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/if} 
  {if logged_in_member_id == "0"}
    {exp:channel:entries status="open"}
    ...
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/if}
```

> If you rely, for some
>   reason, on logged_in_member_id being parsed late, the extension also
>   adds global_member_id and global_group_id for convenience.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/global-member-vars

Comment: Okay sounds good. Can you add the conditional inside the entry tag to avoid duplicating them?

Comment: i think so, because it is now an early config var. But don't make it an advanced conditional, otherwise it is parsed late again. e.g. make it two simple conditionals {if global_group_id=="6"}...{/if}{if global_group_id=="0"}..{/if}

Comment: Download link for this add-on no longer works.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - devot-ee page updated. Do know however, that this extension might not be needed anymore for EE 2.9+